# How to get results from `Collection.find()` in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I successfully connected MongoDB to my Deno API Application. I added todos from my post request from the postman. When I try to get all the Todos from the get request I'm getting this `{}`. what went wrong here?

```
//get todo
const getTodo = async (ctx: RouterContext) => {
  const notes = await notesCollection.find();
  ctx.response.body = notes;
  console.log(notes);
};
```

My Console output is `FindCursor {}`

Comment: Still have issue? `Collection.find()` return `Cursor`, To return result use `notesCollection.find({}).toArray()` [read more](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/),  Happy coding!

Comment: This could be because there is no data in a collection.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue...